# Kubernetes ServiceAccount cannot list nodes

Tags: kubernetes

I'm trying to give my service account `foo` permissions to get a list of the nodes on the cluster (via `kubectl get nodes`). I created a clusterrole and a role binding with these permissions:

```
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: ClusterRole
metadata:
 name: foo-cluster-role
rules:
  - apiGroups: [""]
    resources: ["nodes"]
    verbs: ["get", "list", "watch"]
```

When I run a pod with that service account I'm unable to run `kubectl get nodes`:

```
root@debugger:/# kubectl get nodes
Error from server (Forbidden): nodes is forbidden: User "system:serviceaccount:default:foo" cannot list resource "nodes" in API group "" at the cluster scope
```

Weirdly, when I ask via `kubectl auth can-i`, it tells me I should have access:

```
root@debugger:/# kubectl auth can-i get nodes
Warning: resource 'nodes' is not namespace scoped
yes
```

How do I set up my serviceaccount so I have access to list the nodes on the cluster?

*edit* clusterrolebinding looks like this:

```
kind: RoleBinding
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1
metadata:
  name: foo-binding
subjects:
- kind: ServiceAccount
  name: foo
roleRef:
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: foo-cluster-role
  apiGroup: ""
```

Comment: can you share ClusterRoleBinding also?

Comment: Also check `kubectl auth can-i get nodes  --as=system:serviceaccount:default:foo`

Comment: @hoque added the binding. that kubectl auth can-i also returns yes

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have to create `ClusterRoleBinding`. Please check with following.

```
    apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
    kind: ClusterRole
    metadata:
      name: foo-cluster-role
    rules:
    - apiGroups: [""]
      resources: ["nodes"]
      verbs: ["get", "watch", "list"]
    
    ---
    apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
    kind: ClusterRoleBinding
    metadata:
      name: foo-binding
    subjects:
    - kind: ServiceAccount
      name: foo
      namespace: default
    roleRef:
      kind: ClusterRole
      name: foo-cluster-role
      apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
```

Comment: ah! Just pasting that into my question made me notice I had written `RoleBinding` instead of `ClusterRoleBinding`. Thank you, silly mistake.

Comment: @spike thanks for that, I made the same mistake copy pasting files and did not see it until I read your comment /facepalm

Comment: namespace of the ServiceAccount "foo" in the ClusterRoleBinding is required. It is missing (as of 2023-04-18).